# Angular2: Login with api fails to get data sometimes

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, session-cookies, angular-cookies

I'm trying to login on web with authentication of token got from Web-API. I am saving the token in cookies and proceed my work.

I want to ask that if i am login with admin on one tab and without logout, i will login again.
Then, sometimes the result would not get as expected (data i got sometimes was incomplete).

Is this the issue of cookies ? Is it remembering the previous token that i have not cleared on previous tab login page. What should i do to fix this issue?

Please check the below code of login

```
Login(model: LoginViewModel): Observable<any> {
    // let body = "username=" + model.UserName + "&password=" + model.Password + "&grant_type=password" + "&client_id=" + "&client_secret=";
    let body = "username=" + model.UserName + "&password=" + model.Password + "&grant_type=password";

    let url = APIURL + "/token";

    return this._http.post(url, body, AuthService.OptionsUrlEncoded)
        .map(response => {
            this.AddClaims(response.json())
             this.ExpireTime();
        })

        .catch(this.HandleError);

}
```

Comment: Please describe more precisely what is the behaviour you are witnessing. I don't quite understand your description. Then people can better help :)

Comment: My login function is authenticating and getting token from asp.net Web api. and then save that token in application cookies. I'm having trouble in getting data by using this token on new login tab.

Suppose user A is login on a windows tab. He doesn't logout. Then opens the new windows tab and login again. This time, the data will be inappropriate sometimes

Comment: You should try to better caracterize the "sometimes". With `console.log` calls, try to pinpoint the conditions when it fails.

Comment: Actually that "sometimes" happens in a while. I faced it once last month. So, its really tough for me to configure it by console.log calls. I just don't want to get that type of issue again. 

I think it may be the issue of token mismatch. Can't say clearly without having the failure case. If anything can be done, please suggest.

Comment: Do your tokens have an expiration time? Maybe they just expire after a while and you need to refresh them in case they do.